# Extjs how to add close icon to the combo box

Tags: extjs

how to add close icon to  the combobox list items at right most

```
 Ext.define('ezdi.view.SaveSearchComboboxView', {
        extend : 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
        alias : 'widget.saveSearchComboboxAlias',
        queryMode : 'local',
        id : 'saveSearchComboId',
        store : 'SaveSearchComboboxStore',
        emptyText : 'Saved Searches',
        displayField : 'searchQueryName',
        valueField : 'searchQueryId',
        lazyInit: false
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by adding `triggerXCls` and `onTriggerXClick` to specify any number of additional trigger icons, where "X" is the position of additional trigger.

For example, to add a "clear" icon, you might do something like:

```
{
    ...,
    id: 'saveSearchComboId',
    trigger1Cls: 'x-form-clear-trigger',
    onTrigger1Click: function() {
        this.clearValue();
    }
}
```

Keep in mind there are only a few "default" trigger icons, which can be found here (for classic theme): ext/resources/ext-theme-classic/images/form. These each have their corresponding "x-form-XYZ-trigger" class. For a different trigger icon (like a "close" icon or an "add" icon), you'll need to create your own images as well as the appropriate CSS class that you can apply to triggerXCls.

See this tread for more info: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?190886-How-to-reset-a-Combobox-or-Multiselect-to-no-values-selected